# Calculation from text file

Tags: python

I have a text file containing:

```
SKT:SSG:2:1
NJW:UIA:1:0
SKT:TRP:3:2
SSG:NJW:0:2
```

I want to calculate the number of wins by each team corresponding to the number in the text file. Example:

```
SKT: 2
NJW: 2
UIA: 0
SSG: 0
```

Here's what i have so far:

```
fileName = input("Enter the file name:")
match = open(fileName)
table = []

for line in match:
    contents = line.strip().split(':')
    table.append(contents)
dictionary = {}
for line in table:
    #how do i code the index of the team and it's score?
    .
    .
```

just a moment to test my understanding, if i were to calculate how many times each team wins, i have to ensure python is able to read that for example, **SKT** had a score of **2** against **SSG** of score **1** in game 1,which makes **SKT the winner**. Therefore, **count + 1**

however, I'm confused on how would i place the index of the team name corresponding to it's score. Any help is appreciated. Regards.

Comment: Do you need the table list? Your already iterating over the lines in the file

Comment: build a dictionary of the teams, parse your file, determine the winner, add one score to the winning team in the dictionary

Comment: Try using pandas, though. It's more meant for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a dict to store all the team winning score.

```
res = {}
for line in match:
   team1,team2,score1,score2 = line.split(':')
   if team1 not in res: res[team1] = 0
   if team2 not in res: res[team2] = 0
   if int(score1) == int(score2):
      continue 
   else:
      winner = team1 if int(score1) > int(score2) else team2
      res[winner] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary.

```
fileName = input("Enter the file name:")
match = open(fileName)

d = {}
for line in match:
    x, y, sx, sy = line.split(":")

    if not x in d:
        d[x] = 0
    if not y in d:
        d[y] = 0
    if sx > sy:
        d[x] += 1
    elif sx < sy:
        d[y] += 1


print(d)
```

Result:

```
{'SKT': 2, 'SSG': 0, 'NJW': 2, 'UIA': 0, 'TRP': 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) simplifies the procedure:

```
import collections

scores = collections.defaultdict(int)
for line in table:
    teamA,teamB,scoreA,scoreB = line.split(':')
    # even if scores does not have the team key, += will create it
    scores[teamA] += int(scoreA)
    scores[teamB] += int(scoreB)
```