# Calculation based of index

Tags: python

I have a text file containing:

```
ROX:KT:3:2
JAG:CJ:1:0
KDO:MST:2:1
KDO:ROX:1:3
JAG:KT:2:1
```

I want to calculate the total score for each team. Example:

```
ROX:6
JAG:3
KDO:3
MST:1
KT: 3
```

Here's the code I've worked on:

```
fileName = input("Enter file name:")
match = open(fileName)
table = []

for line in match:
    contents = line.strip()
    table.append(contents)

dictionary = {}
for line in table:
    teamA,teamB,scoreA,scoreB = line.split(':')
    #I'm stuck here onwards
    .
    .
```

From what i could think of, i have to code python to ensure the index of the same team corresponds to the index of the number as displayed in the other section of the text file in order to **obtain the sum**. Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating number of wins from a score](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452802/calculating-number-of-wins-from-a-score)

Comment: Your question in concept is similar to your previous question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452802/calculating-number-of-wins-from-a-score/43452971#43452971). SO is not a programming service so I think it should be closed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
f = open('filename.txt').readlines()

f = [i.strip('\n') for i in f]


f = [i.split(':') for i in f]



dct = {}

for i in f:
   for b in range(len(i[:2])):
       if i[:2][b] not in dct.keys():
           dct[i[:2][b]] = int(i[2:][b])

        else:
           dct[i[:2][b]] += int(i[2:][b])
print dct
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do so using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
import collections

fileName = input("Enter file name:")
match = open(fileName)
table = []

for line in match:
    contents = line.strip()
    table.append(contents)

scores = collections.defaultdict(int)
for line in table:
    teamA,teamB,scoreA,scoreB = line.split(':')
    # even if scores does not have the team key, += will create it
    scores[teamA] += int(scoreA)
    scores[teamB] += int(scoreB)
```

Comment: I just finished my solution with the normal inline if approach, but defaultdict is way better. Thanks for pointing out the pythonic way.